# How can I use JOIN in order to retrieve rows according to WHERE statements in distinct tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I got a database which controls some `orders`, each order has many `items`, naturally, an order is submitted by a user which belongs to a department.

Each user belongs to certain role, so orders are reviewed consecutively by distinct `users` with distinct higher roles. I control the next user who should do something with the order with a `delegate` field.

I will describe some of my tables with its relevant fields:

```
Department:
- id
- name

User:
- id
- name
- department_id
- role

Order:
- id
- user_id
- delegate // Here I got an enum for the multiple roles a user can get

Revision:
- id
- order_id
- user_id
- operation
```

### Query

So what I need is **a query for retrieving all orders whose users belong to a given `department_id` and the `delegate` field equals one provided argument OR where there are records at `revisions` table with `user_id` equal to another provided argument**

### What I got ...

With the aid of Eloquent ORM I got this style of query for first part of my needed result:

```
select `orders`.*, `users`.`department_id` from `orders` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` where `users`.`department_id` = '1' and `delegate` = 'GERENTE DE DEPARTAMENTO' limit 2 offset 0
```

In order to include the *OR where there are records at `revisions` table with `user_id` equal to another provided argument* part of the query I tried to append to the query:

```
JOIN orders on revisions WHERE user_id = 5
```

But didn't work ...

The whole query I tried was:

```
select `orders`.*, `users`.`department_id` from `orders` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` where `users`.`department_id` = '1' and `delegate` = 'GERENTE DE DEPARTAMENTO' JOIN orders on revisions WHERE user_id = 5
```

### Example

I'm using hardcoded arguments in my queries examples as they are from a real example ... In that case I need to get only the whole orders whose users belong to `deparment_id` 1, `delegate` is `'GERENTE DE DEPARTAMENTO'` OR if there are rows at `revisions` table which got the `user_id` set to 5

```
Orders:

+----+---------+-------------------------+
| id | user_id | delegate                |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|  1 |       4 | GERENTE DE DEPARTAMENTO |
|  2 |       2 | SUPERVISOR DE COMPRAS   |
+----+---------+-------------------------+


Revisions:
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | order_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       5 |        2 |
|  2 |       5 |        2 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

A working query should take orders 1 and 2 only. **How can I accomplish it?** I'm interested about the MySQL needed and is a PLUS if it's Eloquent based query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, ie. you need:

`orders that delegate= $delegate AND have user_id= x if that user got as department_id= $department_id at users, OR revisions by user with id = $userId`

then this is the Eloquent way:

```
Order::where('delegate', $delegate)
  ->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($depId) {
    $q->where('department_id', $depId);
  })->orWhereHas('revisions', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
  })
->get();
```

Comment: What I need is `any orders that delegate= $delagete AND have user_id= x if that user got as department_id= $department_id at users, 
   OR revisions by user with id = $userId`

Comment: In this case, does such query assume I set up relationships at the Models?
I ask before I wonder, in `->whereHas('user'...` what exactly user is supposed to be ... a relationship function, a table?

Comment: Yes, `user` is a `Order belongsTo User` relation, and `revisions` is `Order hasMany Revision` relation. You asked for an Eloquent solution so I assumed you have them defined already.

Comment: Great, thanks... how similar is the produced query to the one in the other response?

Comment: It is far from the `left join` `distinct` and stuff. Just build it and use `toSql` instead of `get` and you will see. It basically calls 2 subqueries (1 for each whereHas).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73598/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-jarek-tkaczyk).

Answer (score 1):

You could use left joins.

Your query might look something like this:

```
select distinct `orders`.*, `users`.`department_id` from `orders`
       left join `users` on `order`.`user_id`=`users`.`id`
       left join `revisions` on `order`.`id`=`revisions`.`order_id`
                            and `revisions`.`user_id`=?
    where `users`.`department_id`=?
    and (`order`.`delegate`=? or `revisions`.`id` is not null)
```

Comment: That doesn't include the delegate argument and could duplicate the orders .. :/

Comment: Left joins ensure that the left table (e.g. orders) is shown as is -- i.e. no duplicate rows, no missing rows.

Comment: I just checked and it's duplicating rows

Comment: In the SOP you have `x and y OR z`.  I'm not sure whether to interpret that as `(x and y) OR z` or `x and (y OR z)`, but I think it's pretty clear how to change the query to match :)

Comment: Shoot, yeah rows can be duplicated... need to add a group by.  Try adding `group by orders.id` at the end.

Comment: Aha,  your provided query works almost perfectly excepting the duplicate issue, can you help me add that group by?

Comment: Could you help me obtain the *user name* included in the results?

Comment: Aw, you can figure that one out!  You're already getting the user's department ID, right?  Name will be similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73557/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-awm).

Comment: Sorry, I gotta get back to work.  I think you'll get it figured out~